# Firebase Custom Parameters with the Firebase Event

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I integrated Firebase for Unity, it worked well; but I have problems understanding custom parameters.

I am using Firebase' s level_up event(it is not related but works for my purpose) and I added custom parameters to it like:

```
Parameter(string levelfailedornot, int currentlevel)
```

So a parameter for level_up event looks like this:

```
Parameter("fail", 151)
```

**I thought I could see which level failed how many times, which level is easier than others etc.** The problem is that I can see this custom parameters with values in the "last 30 minutes activities"("fail 151 - 32 times reported" "success 3 - 3 times reported" etc.) at firebase analytics console but I can' t see them other than that panel. How can I achieve this? I added custom parameters reporting to the level_up event but they show only how many times "fail" or "success" reported.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are logging events only in the [debug/test](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) mode.

For events to appear and stay in Firebase Dashboard, ensure all these steps mentioned in the [Get Started guide for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start) are followed in same order.

Since *currentLevel* is int type parameter it is reported as *int* and *levelfailedornot* is *String* parameter reports "fail" or "pass". The screen for event would display all the parameters in view cards along with values received from various devices using your app.

Answer (score 0):

The last 30 minutes activities are updated early, but it takes 6-7 hours before they are added to the long time analysis.
Also, the numeric parameters are only visible as Average and Sum, which are not helpful in your case. If you want to count custom parameter events, it has to be Text type.